# Use a colorbar coming from one plot on an other plot

Tags: matlab, figure, colorbar

I load two images and want to compare them by looking at them. The images are dynamic, so a fixed colorbar does not work here.

So I am displaying two images, the first one initialzes a colorbar with `caxis auto`. Now I want to reuse the found out caxis on the next figure, how can I do this?

```
figure;imshow(firstimage);
caxis auto;
c = colorbar;




figure;
imshow(secondimage);
colorbar(c) %does not work but shows what I want to have
```

Comment: I don't know if it'll help but the second time you put `colobar` not `colorbar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can just run something like:

```
figure;
imshow(firstimage);
caxis auto;
c = colorbar;
cmin = c.Limits(1);
cmax = c.Limits(2);
figure;
imshow(secondimage);
colorbar
caxis([cmin cmax]);
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer, however I get the following error: Insufficient number of outputs from right hand side of equal sign to satisfy assignment.

Error in ShowMyResults (line 9)
[min max] = c.Limits;

Comment: @Kev1n91 see the edit for a fix. I also changed the variable names to not override `min` and `max`